# copy data from source sheet to last row of destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I would like to carry out the captioned task with the code

```
Sub COPYTOLASTROW()
Dim LRDest As Long, SrcRng As Range
With Sheets("source")
Set SrcRng = .Range("B16:E20")
End With
With Sheets("summary")
LRDest = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 1)
End With
End Sub
```

The code above was based on the thread [Copy data from one sheet to the last row of another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303076/copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-the-last-row-of-another-sheet).

However, I only want to paste VALUES to destination.  What should I do to the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
SrcRng.Copy .Cells(LRDest + 1, 1)
```

with:

```
SrcRng.Copy 
.Range("A" & LRDest + 1).PasteSpecial paste:= xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Hi your code does the job.  Thank you!